# container div doesn't expanding despite height:100% property

Tags: css, html

The container div("sayfa" in my code)is not expanding even though I use height:100%; property. I used border to see it's height and it's 0 which results footer being in front of the content if content is long enough.
HTML:

```
<div class="sayfa">
        <div class="sutun">
            <div class="icerik">
                <a href=#>En Son Eklenenler</a><hr/>
                <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
            </div>
            <div class="icerik">
                <a href=#>En Çok Okunanlar</a><hr/>
                <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sutun">
            <div class="icerik">
                <a href=#>En Çok Beğenilenler</a><hr/>
                <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sutun">
            <div class="icerik">
                <a href=#>En Çok Tıklanan Yazarlar</a><hr/>
                <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="altlik">
    </div>
```

And CSS:

```
div.sayfa{
width:999px;
height:100%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
border:solid;
}
div.icerik{
margin-right:10px;
margin-left:10px;
width:288px;
height:100%;
border:solid;
border-radius:20px;
background-image:url('/grsl/icerik.jpg');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
padding-left:25px;
padding-top:15px;
border-width:1px;
border-color:#393939;
box-shadow:4px 4px 7px #000;
padding-bottom:20px;
margin-top:20px;
}
div.icerik > hr {
margin-left:-25px;
}
div.icerik > a {
text-decoration:none;
color:#3E4E95;
font-weight:bold;
font-family:arial;
}
div.icerik > li{
list-style:none;
text-decoration:none;
line-height:23px;
}
div.icerik > li > a{
text-decoration:none;
color:#000;
font-family:arial;
}
div.icerik > li:hover > a{
text-decoration:underline;
}
div.sutun{
width:333px;
height:100%;
float:left;
margin-left:-5px;
}
div.altlik{
width:100%;
height:100px;
text-align:center;
background-color:#393939;
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
margin-top:20px;
}
```

"Sayfa" is container div. "Sutun" seperates sayfa into three parts. "Icerik" is those blue boxes. "Altlik" is the footer.

Answer (score 3):

Floating elements doesn't affect the size of the parent, but you can use the `overflow` style to make it contain the children:

```
div.sayfa{
  width:999px;
  overflow:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  border:solid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add below code right above the closing div of `sayfa`.

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

**Edit**

```
<div class="sayfa">
    <div class="sutun">
        <div class="icerik">
            <a href=#>En Son Eklenenler</a><hr/>
            <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
        </div>
        <div class="icerik">
            <a href=#>En Çok Okunanlar</a><hr/>
            <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sutun">
        <div class="icerik">
            <a href=#>En Çok Beğenilenler</a><hr/>
            <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sutun">
        <div class="icerik">
            <a href=#>En Çok Tıklanan Yazarlar</a><hr/>
            <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Birinci Kitap</a></li>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:float;"></div>
----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----
</div>
<div class="altlik">
</div>
```